# Create Outlook emails and attach files in a folder with a maximum number of files per email

Tags: vba, outlook, attachment

I need to create Outlook emails and attach a maximum of 10 files.
If there are 16 files then 2 emails should be created, the first containing 10 files, the second containing the remaining 6 files.

When I try to attach files, it gives

> Object doesn't support this property or method.

```vb
Sub attach()
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim strbody As String
    'Dim temp_Attach As Object
    
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .Show
        .Title = "Select a Folder"
        sFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
    
    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set f = fs.GetFolder(sFolder)
    Set fls = f.Files
    
    Z = 10
    
    For d = 0 To fls.Count - 1 Step 10
    
        Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
        'On Error Resume Next
        With OutMail
            .To = "abc@gmail.com"
            .CC = ""
            .subject = "file"
            
            y = 0
            For Each x In fls
                If y < Z Then
                    .Attachements.Add (sFolder & "\" & x.Name)
                    y = y + 1
                Else
                    Exit For
                End If
            
                Z = Z + 10
            
            Next
            .Display
            
        End With
    
    Next
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You misspelled the word `Attachments` (you have it as Attach***e***ments).

Answer (score 0):

The following code works like a charm on my side:

```
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    
With OutMail
      .To = "abc@gmail.com"
      .CC = ""
      .subject = "file"
        
      y = 0
     
      For Each x In fls
        If y < Z Then
           .Attachments.Add (sFolder & "\" & x.Name)
           y = y + 1
        Else
           Exit For
        End If
        
        Z = Z + 10
        
     Next
     .Display
        
  End With

Next
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I have another issue. Could you please help? The code just creates 2 emails and attaches 16 files to both emails. So, it just makes 2 identical emails. However, I need first email to only contain first 10 files and second email to contain the remaining 6.  If there are 26 files in a folder - same logic. First email -10 files, second email next 10 files, third email remaining 6 files

Answer (score 0):

With two running counts of the attachments being added,

- display when the per email limit is reached and restart the email limit count.
- display when the folder total is reached.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub attach()

    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    
    Dim sFolder As Variant
    Dim sFile As Variant
    
    Dim fs As Object
    Dim f As Object
    Dim fls As Object
    Dim flsCount As Long
    
    Dim attLimit As Long
    Dim attCountEmail As Long
    Dim attCountTotal As Long
    
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        If .Show = -1 Then ' if OK is pressed
            .Title = "Select a Folder"
            sFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With
    
    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set f = fs.GetFolder(sFolder)
    Set fls = f.Files
    
    flsCount = fls.Count
    Debug.Print " flsCount: " & flsCount
    
    attLimit = 10
    
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    
    attCountEmail = 0
    attCountTotal = 0
    
    For Each sFile In fls
        
        If attCountEmail = 0 Then
            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
            With OutMail
                .To = "abc@gmail.com"
                .CC = ""
                .Subject = "file"
            End With
        End If
            
        If attCountEmail < attLimit Then
            OutMail.Attachments.Add (sFolder & "\" & sFile.Name)
                    
            attCountEmail = attCountEmail + 1
            Debug.Print " attCountEmail: " & attCountEmail
                
            attCountTotal = attCountTotal + 1
            Debug.Print " attCountTotal: " & attCountTotal
                
        End If
    
        If attCountTotal = flsCount Then
            OutMail.display
            
        ElseIf attCountEmail = attLimit Then
            OutMail.display
            attCountEmail = 0
        End If

    Next
        
End Sub
```